# Selenium - how to get text when element contains text + element

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I have elements like this:

```
<div id="x">
"abc"
<strong>xyz</strong>
"def"
</div>
```

I am trying:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("x")).getText()
```

Result is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetch text using getAttribute method, e.g.

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("x")).getAttribute("textContent")
```